# Why do I have a 'User was removed' entry on my reputation change sheet?

Tags: discussion, support

This is actually an odd question for me, so let me explain it as best I can...

After logging back into the Stack Exchange Network after some time, I got a notification stating that my 3D Printing Stack Exchange Profile has had 10 reputation deducted.

Now, after reading the 'Read more' link provided by Stack, I still fail to understand why I have this entry on my reputation change sheet. I don't recall voting to close anyone's profile on the Stack Exchange (that's just being cruel IMHO)

Attached is a screenshot of my reputation change sheet.

> [image: Reputation change]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user's account was deleted, for whatever reason. Therefore, any votes that they had cast in the past were automatically deleted, and any associated reputation changes were lost. A lot of other people, across many SE sites, also lost a lot of reputation on 25/05/2019 as the user, whose account was removed, was a frequent voter.

See the answers to [Change the criteria for vote retention upon account removal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/328646/change-the-criteria-for-vote-retention-upon-account-removal).

I know nothing more than that. I did mention it in [chat], see [this post](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/50474487#50474487).

Comment: Ah. That makes more sense. It also appears that I misinterpreted the explanation provided by Stack. Therefore, thanks for clearing this up. Marked as Answer

Comment: @GipsyD - You got a -10 here ... I lost 800 points on Mechanics.SE during the same sweep. Argh.